# Crear JSON con un elemento raíz que dentro tiene otros elementos pero no debe ser array

Tags: java, json

Buenos dias estoy tratando de construir un JSON con las clases JSONObject y JSONArray. El problema que no se solucionar es que con JSONObject hago como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
{

nombre: "Alberto"

apellido: "Perez" 

}
```

Y con  el JSONArray pues una lista. Lo que no consigo hacer es lo siguiente, que no es ni como el ejemplo de arriba ni como una lista.
Que sería asi:

```
datos: {

         nombre: "Pedro"
         
         apellido: "Perez"


}
```

¿Me vale la clase JSONObject para este ejemplo que no se como resolver o se usaria otra clase diferente?  Muchas gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 1):

Bueno he encontrado yo mismo la solución.
que pretendía conseguir:

```json
{ nombre: "pepe", apellido: "Navarro", Dirección: { calle: "margarita", numero: "24"}, edad: "18"}
```

Como lo he conseguido:

```java
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
JSONObject subdata = new JSONObject();
data.put("nombre",pepe);
data.put("apellido",Navarro);
data.put("Direccion",subdata);
subdata.put("calle", Margarita)
subdata.put("numero", 24)
data.put("edad",18);
```

Espero que les sea de ayuda.